# socket.io authentication with socketio-auth

Tags: node.js, authentication, redis, socket.io

I've a server in node.js & Express and i use socket.io for real-time messaging and [socketio-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-auth) module for authentication,I setup everything for using this module but i found nothing about `db` object and `findUser` that the auther used in examples(not even an single line of comment about them) to work with,should i implement them myself,right?
if anyone have a working example of using or implementing them with redis i'll be grateful to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `db` and `findUser` object is from MongoDb and not related to socket.io. I would recommend you look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/ to gain a better understanding as to why they are used